# How much diskspace is taken by git commit

Tags: git

According to this page 
http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/git/git-1.shtml

A commit object contains three things:

> - A set of files, reflecting the state of a project at a given point in time.
> - References to parent commit objects.
> - An SHA1 name, a 40-character string that uniquely identifies the commit
>     object. The name is composed of a hash
>     of relevant aspects of the commit, so
>     identical commits will always have the
>     same name.

My question is regarding first point:
        If my current project size is 10MB , so adding a new commit will take another 10MB ? since according to first point each commit contains set of files reflecting project state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure the other answers have really addressed your question completely.

Git stores commits and actual file contents separately. A commit doesn't contain files -- it contains references to the *hashes* of files that the commit contains. Files are stored separately from commits, and if two commits have the same version of a file, both of those commits will refer to the same *hash*, but the file itself is not duplicated. If a file changes between commits, the file is stored twice, each version of the file has its own hash, and the commits will refer to different hashes.

Say you start with one commit, which contains two files, a.txt and b.txt, each of which hashes to a different value:

```
Commit 1:
Filename    |    Hash
---------------------
a.txt       | abcdef111111
b.txt       | ghijkl222222
```

Note that the commit does not contain the file contents. Git has stored the contents of the files, and the hashes, elsewhere.

```
File store:
Hash         |    File contents
---------------------------------
abcdef111111 | hello world
ghijkl222222 | int main()
```

Say you update a.txt, and make a new commit. First, Git stores the new version of the file in its store of file contents:

```
File store:
Hash         |    File contents
---------------------------------
abcdef111111 | hello world
ghijkl222222 | int main()
zyxwvu999999 | goodbye world     <-- new entry
```

And the new commit points to that hash as containing the contents of a.txt:

```
Commit 2:
Filename    |    Hash
---------------------
a.txt       | zyxwvu999999
b.txt       | ghijkl222222
```

Since b.txt did not change, there was no need to store it again. The second commit just refers to the same hash as the first commit.

Answer (score 2):

No. A Git commit only contains references to the tree, parent SHAs (which contain the history) and other info such as author, comments, timestamp, etc. The actual changes are not stored in the commit. A nice description is given in [this page](http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html), and from the same article:

> Note that a commit does not itself contain any information about what actually changed; all changes are calculated by comparing the contents of the tree referred to by this commit with the trees associated with its parents.

In SVN and related vcs, they store two copies of the same file, one in the working directory and one in `.svn/` which is used to diff and commit. As a result, in big projects, the size of the repos grows considerably with commits. For e.g., the entire Mozilla project repository is nearly 12 GB using SVN, whereas the same is only about 420 MB with git <sup>[[1]](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnComparison)</sup>

Comment: So you mean to say in SVN a commit in the situation like the author says would add 10MB to the repo?

Comment: **> project repository is nearly 12 GB using SVN**. Nope, this is wrong. Have you tested this yourself? A common myth about repo size according to http://svnvsgit.com/

Answer (score 2):

No.

A commit includes an object tree that snapshots the source tree, but the object tree reuses unchanged objects from previous snapshots. So each commit only adds objects for files and directories with changes, it does not store the entire state all over.

*On top of that*, Git will also periodically pack loose objects into “packfiles”, which store the contents of many files at once, but in which files can refer to parts of each other (roughly). This can be extremely effective at removing redundancy.

As a result, the total size of the `.git` directory of a project containing years of history is usually a tiny fraction of the total size of the working directory with just the checkout of the current state.

As an extreme example, I have a repository into which I commit SQL dumps from a production database. At this time, the SQL dump file is 56MB. The `.git` directory containing *377 commits* (ie. over 1 year’s worth of backups) is *just 32MB*. (Compressing this file with `xz -Mmax -9` cuts it down to 2.4MB, but with 370 such files that’s still close to 1GB/year.) So I am using Git as a very convenient type of compressed archive.

Answer (score 1):

No. Each commit itself is only a pointer to the previous commit and a snapshot of the state of the tree ( and other metadata like the commit message ). Each commit doesn't add those files ( actually the content of the files) to the repo again.

When the content of a file changes, say, the new content is added to the objects and the tree is updated to this new content for the file and the commit would point to this new tree state.

Do a `git cat-file commit HEAD` and you can get some idea on what a commit really has.

Also, look at [`Git from bottom up`](http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf) ( free) or the `Version Control with Git` book, both have some good explanation on the concepts of blobs, trees and commits.

Answer (score -1):

Only the [delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) between commits are stored. All the SCMs that I know of store deltas. However, the case may be different if the files in consideration contain binary data. Then, a delta may be impossible.

Comment: Git does not store deltas - every file is stored in its entirety, but files that do not change between commits are not stored twice.

Comment: @Mike: Git does (eventually) store deltas in “pack files” (see *[git-pack-objects(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-objects.html)*; usually done automatically via *[git-gc(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html)*). However, such delta encoding is just a implementation detail of how Git can store objects, **not** part of the object model itself (blobs, trees, commits, tags).

Comment: @Chris Johnsen - pack files are not pertinent to the question as they don't come into the picture when we commit. @Alan Haggai Alavi - `delta between commits are stored`, especially in the context of doing commits is wrong. @Adam Bernier - this is the community saying that the answer is not correct, there will not be "system cleanup"

Comment: @manojlds: It is certainly not clear to me that the question was strictly focused on the situation of new commits. It seems to me that the phrase “adding a new commit” was just the easiest way to talk about two different repository states (where overall disk usage should reasonably differ by some amount).